# Multinode couchbase cluster performance issue

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We have a Couchbase cluster running consisting of 3 Nodes.
Two nodes have enabled the data, index, query and search service, 
The third node is a data only service.

When a "larger" dataset of ~400 entries are created, it takes up to 15 minutes until the documents can be fully queried.

The cluster is accessed by Spring-Data repositories and the Couchbase-Java-Client shipped with Spring-Data-Couchbase only(see versions below).

Performing the same request in our staging environment with a single node cluster and the same GSI Index, the data is, compared to the production state, instantaneously available. So my conclusion would be, that there is an issue with the node sync or the caching in Spring-Data-Couchbase.

Is there a configuration I miss, that would speed up the node sync or anyone else facing the same problem?

Versions:

- Couchbase Server 6.0.0 Community
- Spring-Boot 2.2.4
- Spring-Data-Couchbase 3.2.4
- Couchbase Java Client 2.7.11

Comment: I doubt that it is something related to node sync. It is a very stable feature in couchbase. I wonder if it is something related to the disc/memory of the server. Do you have indexes in production as well? Have you tried to query the data using different indexes? Have you configured Spring Data to be strong consistent?

Comment: I would also recommend you to insert a few documents and try to query them right after

Comment: I don´t have enabled the strong consistency but I will do next week and check if the behavior is improved.

I indeed have sometimes, especially when running integration tests the problem, that the document is not available for a couple of seconds when i try to query them. but in this case there is only a one node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that, for one node set only data service and increase the memory size as much as you can.

for 1.node set only data service

for 2.node set data and index service

for 3.node set search and query

if you are not using search service set nodes like these

for 1.node set only data service

for 2.node set only data service

for 3.node set index and query

Comment: This does not work with the community edition since only "data only" nodes or "all service" nodes are allowed to be configured.